# What is the status of applying the "values" function to a hash or array reference?

Tags: perl

Given that `$struct` is a data structure that can be either a hash or an array reference, I have some code that looks like this:

```
for (ref($struct) eq "HASH" ? values %$struct : values @$struct) {  
    # process $_
    ...
}
```

I would like to use the new functionality of the `values` function (to accept a reference to an unblessed hash or array) to write this instead, which works in my 5.14.2 release:

```
for (values $struct) {  
    # process $_ 
    ...
}
```

So much prettier!

But the documentation for `values` says that this feature is "highly experimental."  It has been around for several releases now (5.12 through 5.16.0 as far as I can tell).  Does anyone know what the status is?  How is the experiment working out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's marked as experimental because it's a controversial change. It's controversial because it doesn't work on all references to hashes.* No new has been discovered since the feature was introduced, but I don't think anyone expected any new problems to be discovered.

---

* — `values($hash)` can fail where `values(%$hash)` would succeed. Your original code has exactly the same problem, so this "limitation" of `values` isn't a problem for you.

Comment: I don't understand how my original code could fail since it uses `%$hash`, can you explain further?  Also, what I'm wondering is if anyone knows if the change on the verge of being reverted, or considered permanent, or is it going to be "experimental" forever.

Comment: Fails for a blessed hash. Fails for an object presenting a hash interface through overloading.

Comment: The documentation says it must be an unblessed reference.

Comment: Of course it is. If it wasn't a known issue, how could it be controversial?